# Add ODBC driver for Office 365 (local install) in Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, odbc, microsoft-excel, ssis

For some ETL operations using Microsoft's SSIS system, we need to read data from an XLSX file accessible from the database server (Windows Server 2016, Microsoft SQL Server 2017 on prem).
When creating the package on the dev machine with Office 365 installed locally, reading from the XLSX file (from Office 365 on prem installation) is workin fine, but as soon as the SSIS package is deployed on the server, the `ConnectionManager` cannot open the connection to the XLSX file.

Our assumption is, that there's some package or driver missing (ODBC, ADO.NET, ACE, OleDB or whatever...), which allows for reading from Excel spreadsheets. But which package is needed?